# Rails 4: Action called from Javascript doesn't see model association (NoMethodError)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working through "Rails: Up & Running, 2nd Ed.", http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596522018.do. I'm new to Javascript and have limited experience with associations in Rails.

I am trying to implement cycling through the slides using jQuery in Rails 4 instead of Prototype as used in the original.

When I call the show_slide action from 'show.rs.erb', Rails doesn't see the association:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `slides' for #<Hash:0x007f8f71d49a60> Did you mean? slice slice!)
```

Using pry I can see that `session[:slideshow]` and `session[:slide_index]` contain the correct values.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

**Leigh

---

### Here's the solution:

```
def show
  @slideshow = Slideshow.find(params[:id])
  session[:slideshow_id] = params[:id]
  session[:slide_index] = 0
  @slide = @slideshow.slides[0]
end

def show_slide
  @slideshow = Slideshow.find(session[:slideshow_id])
  session[:slide_index] += 1
  @slide = @slideshow.slides[session[:slide_index]] 
  if @slide == nil 
     session[:slide_index] = 0 
     @slide = @slideshow.slides[0] 
  end 
  render :partial => "show_slide"
end
```

---

### Code details

show.js.erb:

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    setInterval(function(){
      $('#slides').load('/show_slide');
    }, 2000);
  });
```

slideshows#show_slide:

```
  def show_slide
    @slideshow = session[:slideshow]
    session[:slide_index] += 1
    # binding.pry
    @slide = @slideshow.slides[session[:slide_index]] # => NoMethodError (undefined method `slides' for #<Hash:0x007f8f71d49a60> Did you mean? slice slice!)
    if @slide == nil
      session[:slide_index] = 0
      @slide = @slideshow.slides[0]
    end
    render :partial => "show_slide"
  end
```

The "slideshow.slides" association works in views/slideshows/index.html.erb:

```
<% for slideshow in @slideshows %> 
  <div class="slideshow-summary"> 
    <div class="slideshow-caption"> 
        <strong><%= slideshow.name %> </strong>
      <small>(<%= slideshow.slides.size %> slides)</small> 
    </div> 
    <div class="slideshow-thumbnails"> 
      <% 5.times do |i| -%> 
        <%= thumbnail_tag slideshow.slides[i] %> 
      <% end -%> 
      &nbsp;<strong>. . .</strong> 
    </div> 
    <div class="slideshow-controls"> 
        <%= link_to 'Play', slideshow, :remote => true %> 
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_slideshow_path(slideshow) %> 
        <%= link_to 'Delete', slideshow, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
  <br /> 
<% end %>
```

but NOT here:

```
# class SlideshowsController < ApplicationController
def show_slide
  @slideshow = session[:slideshow]
  session[:slide_index] += 1
  # binding.pry
  @slide = @slideshow.slides[session[:slide_index]] # NoMethodError (undefined method `slides' for #<Hash:0x007fa574ac11d0> Did you mean? slice slice!)

  if @slide == nil
    session[:slide_index] = 0
    @slide = @slideshow.slides[0]
  end
  render :partial => "show_slide"
end
```

show_slide.html.erb:

```
<%= image_tag "photos/#{@slide.photo.filename}" %>
<h4><%= get_photo_name_from_filename(@slide.photo) %></h4>
```

show.html.erb:

```
<p><i><%= @slideshow.name %></i></p>
<% if @slide %>
<div id="slides">
  <%= render :partial => "show_slide"%>
</div>
<% end %>
```

slideshows#show:

```
# class SlideshowsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @slideshow = Slideshow.find(params[:id])
    session[:slideshow] = @slideshow
    session[:slide_index] = 0
    @slide = @slideshow.slides[0]
  end
```

Models:

```
class Slideshow < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :slides
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :slides
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

  validates_presence_of :filename 

    scope :with_filetype_jpg, lambda {{:conditions => "filename like '%.jpg'" }}
  scope :with_thumbnail, lambda {{:conditions => "thumbnail not null and thumbnail != ''"}}
  scope :with_filetype, 
    lambda {|ftype| {:conditions => ["filename like ?", "%.#{ftype}"] } } 
end

class Slide < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :slideshow
  belongs_to  :photo

  acts_as_list  :scope => "slideshow_id"
end
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'spring'
end
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-generators', '~> 3.3.4'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'acts_as_tree'
```

Debugger session:

```
slideshows_controller.rb @ line 15 SlideshowsController#show:

    12: def show
    13:   @slideshow = Slideshow.find(params[:id])
    14:   session[:slideshow] = @slideshow
 => 15:   binding.pry
    16:   session[:slide_index] = 0
    17:   @slide = @slideshow.slides[0]
    18: end

[1] pry(#<SlideshowsController>)> @slideshow
=> #<Slideshow:0x007f86dce8c320
 id: 1,
 name: "Interesting Pictures",
 created_at: Thu, 24 Mar 2016 21:03:56 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 24 Mar 2016 21:03:56 UTC +00:00>
[2] pry(#<SlideshowsController>)> session[:slideshow]
=> #<Slideshow:0x007f86dce8c320
 id: 1,
 name: "Interesting Pictures",
 created_at: Thu, 24 Mar 2016 21:03:56 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 24 Mar 2016 21:03:56 UTC +00:00>
[3] pry(#<SlideshowsController>)> exit
```

---

```
slideshows_controller.rb @ line 23 SlideshowsController#show_slide:

    21: def show_slide
    22:   @slideshow = session[:slideshow]
 => 23:   binding.pry
    24:   session[:slide_index] += 1
    25:   @slide = @slideshow.slides[0]
    26:   # @slide = @slideshow.slides[session[:slide_index]]
    27:   if @slide == nil
    28:     session[:slide_index] = 0
    29:     @slide = @slideshow[:slides][0]
    30: 
    31:     # @slide = @slideshow.slides[0]
    32:   end
    33:   render :partial => "show_slide"
    34: end

[1] pry(#<SlideshowsController>)> @slideshow
=> {"id"=>1,
 "name"=>"Interesting Pictures",
 "created_at"=>"2016-03-24T21:03:56.000Z",
 "updated_at"=>"2016-03-24T21:03:56.000Z"}
[2] pry(#<SlideshowsController>)> session[:slideshow]
=> {"id"=>1,
 "name"=>"Interesting Pictures",
 "created_at"=>"2016-03-24T21:03:56.000Z",
 "updated_at"=>"2016-03-24T21:03:56.000Z"}
[3] pry(#<SlideshowsController>)>
```

Comment: If `slides` is not a method on `@slideshow` is it a hash key? `@slide = @slideshow[:slides][session[:slide_index]]`?

Comment: I think `@slideshow.slides` is a method produced by `has_many` defined in `class Slideshow`. In the `slideshow#show` action this does not produce an error:

    `@slide = @slideshow.slides[0]`

Comment: oh ok. Then it looks like you get a Hash from `session[:slideshow]` instead of the model which you got from `Slideshow.find(...)`

Comment: That's a good observation! It should be a Slideshow object and in the `show` action it is a Slideshow object in `session[:slideshow]`. When `session[:slideshow]` is accessed in `show_slide`, it returns a hash of the object. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: I added the debugger session.

Comment: Probably if you need to store this info in the session (so it persists across requests) I would recommend storing the id, and then use something like `Slideshow.find(session[:slideshow_id])` to get the object on subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `@slideshow` is a Hash, you need to access its contents using keys (not dot notation like you would in javascript, for example).

`@slideshow[:some_key]`

**Edit:**

But in your case you want a model instance, so you would actually want to load the `@slideshow` from the database rather than from the session object.

Store the slideshow's id in the session (assuming you need access to it across requests), and then read from the database via that id on subsequent requests.

You could also store whatever relevant info you need from the slideshow in the session and avoid reading from the database each time. But in general you want to be careful about what you store in the session. See [Rails session security](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions).

Comment: Thanks! That worked and I appreciate your help a lot!